# React-Router onChange hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am having issues getting the onChange hook in react-router to work properly. Here is my routes file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import TestOne from './Pages/testone';
import TestTwo from './Pages/testtwo';

function logUpdate() {
    console.log('Current URL: ' + window.location.pathname);
}

const Routes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        {/* App Routes */}
        <Route path="/" component={App} lang={lang}>
            <Route path="/testone" component={TestOne} onUpdate={logUpdate} />
            <Route path="/testtwo" component={TestTwo} onUpdate={logUpdate} />
        </Route>
    </Router>);

export default Routes;
```

My understanding is, that the function logUpdate will be triggered on each state change. However, it is only triggered when I reload the corresponding page via F5.

My menu is using simple Links e.g.:

```
<div>
<Link to="/testone">Test One</Link>
<Link to="/testtwo">Test Two</Link>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`onUpdate`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.8.1/docs/API.md#onupdate) needs to be declared on the `Router` instance not `Route`s. Although, `Route`s can declare [`onChange`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.8.1/docs/API.md#onchangeprevstate-nextstate-replace-callback) and [`onEnter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.8.1/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback) hooks - it's probably what you were looking for.

Comment: Great, can't believe I've missed that! Thanks Igorsvee

Comment: These links are for version 2.X, now react-router on 4.0  :)

Comment: on version 4 onUpdate was removed from Router component. See this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911309/how-to-listen-to-route-changes-in-react-router-v4

Answer (score 0):

I'm using react-router ^2.4.0 and onUpdate did not work for me. I have instead used onChange on my base Route component.

```
const Routes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        {/* App Routes */}
        <Route path="/" component={App} lang={lang} onChange={logUpdate}>
            <Route path="/testone" component={TestOne} />
            <Route path="/testtwo" component={TestTwo} />
        </Route>
    </Router>);
```