# How to listen to route changes in react router v4?

Tags: react-router-v4

I have a couple of buttons that acts as routes. Everytime the route is changed, I want to make sure the button that is active changes.

Is there a way to listen to route changes in react router v4?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3554

Answer (score 211, accepted):

I use `withRouter` to get the `location` prop. When the component is updated because of a new route, I check if the value changed:

```js
@withRouter
class App extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    location: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  // ...

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      this.onRouteChanged();
    }
  }

  onRouteChanged() {
    console.log("ROUTE CHANGED");
  }

  // ...
  render(){
    return <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/checkout" component={CheckoutPage} />
        <Route path="/success" component={SuccessPage} />
        // ...
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
  }
}
```

Comment: Use 'this.props.location.pathname' in react router v4.

Comment: @ledfusion I am doing the same and using `withRouter`, but I am getting error `You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>`. I don't see any `<Router/>` component in above code. So how is it working?

Comment: Hi @maverick. I'm not sure how your code looks like, but in the example above, the `<Switch>` component is acting as the de-facto router. Only the first `<Route>` entry to have a matching path, will be rendered. 
There is no need of any `<Router/>` component in this scenario

Comment: to use @withRouter you need to install npm install --save-dev transform-decorators-legacy

Comment: how exactly is withRouter.

Comment: I was going crazy checking if this was a problem with `history.push`, but the problem was visiting the same route and `componentDidUpdate` came to the rescue.

Comment: Sometimes we are so dependent on API's we forget the basics like this solution, thanks man!

Answer (score 106):

v5.1 introduces the useful hook `useLocation`

https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/#uselocation

```js
import { Switch, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

function usePageViews() {
  let location = useLocation()

  useEffect(
    () => {
      ga.send(['pageview', location.pathname])
    },
    [location]
  )
}

function App() {
  usePageViews()
  return <Switch>{/* your routes here */}</Switch>
}
```

Comment: Just a note as I was having trouble with an error: `Cannot read property 'location' of undefined at useLocation`. You need to make sure that the useLocation() call is not in the same component that puts the router into the tree: [see here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/7015)

Comment: this does not trigger the action on nested routes unfortunately

Comment: This is the neatest and shortest solution.

Answer (score 102):

To expand on the above, you will need to get at the history object. If you are using `BrowserRouter`, you can import `withRouter` and wrap your component with a [higher-order component (HoC)](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) in order to have access via props to the history object's properties and functions.

```js
    import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

    const myComponent = ({ history }) => {

        history.listen((location, action) => {
            // location is an object like window.location
            console.log(action, location.pathname, location.state)
        });

        return <div>...</div>;
    };

    export default withRouter(myComponent);
```

The only thing to be aware of is that withRouter and most other ways to access the `history` seem to pollute the props as they de-structure the object into it.

As others have said, this has been superseded by the hooks exposed by react router and it has a memory leak. If you are registering listeners in a functional component you should be doing so via useEffect and unregistering them in the return of that function.

Comment: The answer helped me to understand something regardless of the question:). But fix `withRoutes` to `withRouter`.

Comment: Yep, sorry, thanks for pointing that out.  I've amended the post. I put the correct import at the top of the question and then mis-spelt it in the code example.

Comment: I think the [current version of withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md) passes `history` rather than the variable `listen`.

Comment: It would be good to amend the post to demonstrate unlistening; this code has a memory leak in it.

Comment: you should subscribe only once! Now you will subscribe on each component re render.

Answer (score 42):

`withRouter`, `history.listen`, and `useEffect` (React Hooks) works quite nicely together:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const Component = ({ history }) => {
    useEffect(() => history.listen(() => {
        // do something on route change
        // for my example, close a drawer
    }), [])

    //...
}

export default withRouter(Component)
```

The listener callback will fire any time a route is changed, and the return for `history.listen` is a shutdown handler that plays nicely with `useEffect`.

Answer (score 41):

You should to use [history v4](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) lib.

Example from [there](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#listening)

```
history.listen((location, action) => {
  console.log(`The current URL is ${location.pathname}${location.search}${location.hash}`)
  console.log(`The last navigation action was ${action}`)
})
```

Comment: The history.pushState() and history.replaceState() calls don't trigger the popstate event, so this alone won't cover all route changes.

Comment: @Ryan It seems that `history.push` does trigger `history.listen`. See the **Using a Base URL** example in [history v4 docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/README.md). Because that `history` is actually a wrapper of the native `history` object of a browser, it doesn’t behave exactly like the native one.

Comment: This feels like a better solution, as often times you need to listen to route changes for event pushing, which is unrelated to react component lifecycle events.

Comment: Potential memory leak! Very important that you do this!
"When you attach a listener using history.listen, it returns a function that can be used to remove the listener, which can then be invoked in cleanup logic:
`const unlisten = history.listen(myListener);
unlisten();`

Comment: Go here for documentation on history package. https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md

Comment: @DehandeCroos Is there still a memory leak if this is used in a `useEffect` call?

Comment: Yes!! You need to unlisten inside an effect. An effect can return a function, React will run it when it is time to clean up. You should unlisten inside this.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1

Answer (score 22):

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router';

function MyApp() {

  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
      console.log('route has been changed');
      ...your code
  },[location.pathname]);

}
```

with hooks

Comment: Holly Jesys! how does it work?      Your answer is cool!       buti put debugger point in *useEffect* but any time i changed the pathname the location stayed **undefined**? can you share any good article? becuase it's hard to find any clear information

Comment: Use `react-router-dom` instead of `react-router`

Answer (score 13):

With hooks:

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { history as historyShape } from 'react-router-prop-types'

const DebugHistory = ({ history }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('> Router', history.action, history.location)
  }, [history.location.key])

  return null
}

DebugHistory.propTypes = { history: historyShape }

export default withRouter(DebugHistory)
```

Import and render as `<DebugHistory>` component

Answer (score 8):

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Scroll = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [history.location.pathname]);

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Does it also watch hash changes? route/a#1 --> route/a#2

Comment: It also has to be inside the `<Router> ` element, otherwise you get `TypeError: history is undefined`.

Answer (score 6):

With react Hooks, I am using `useEffect`

```
import React from 'react'
const history = useHistory()
const queryString = require('query-string')
const parsed = queryString.parse(location.search)
const [search, setSearch] = useState(parsed.search ? parsed.search : '')

useEffect(() => {
  const parsedSearch = parsed.search ? parsed.search : ''
  if (parsedSearch !== search) {
    // do some action! The route Changed!
  }
}, [location.search])
```

in this example, Im scrolling up when the route change:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const ScrollToTop = () => {
  const location = useLocation()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }, [location.key])

  return null
}

export default ScrollToTop
```

Answer (score 3):

In some cases you might use `render` attribute instead of `component`, in this way:

```
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
    }

    onRouteChange (pageId) {
        console.log(pageId);
    }

    render () {
        return  <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact render={(props) => { 
                        this.onRouteChange('home');
                        return <HomePage {...props} />;
                    }} />
                    <Route path="/checkout" exact render={(props) => { 
                        this.onRouteChange('checkout');
                        return <CheckoutPage {...props} />;
                    }} />
                </Switch>
    }
}
```

Notice that if you change state in `onRouteChange` method, this could cause 'Maximum update depth exceeded' error.

Answer (score 3):

**For React Router v6 & React Hooks**,
You need to use **useLocation** instead of useHistory as it is deprecated

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

export default function Component() {

const history = useLocation();

   useEffect(() => {
    console.log('> Router', history.pathname)      
}, [history.pathname]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For functional components try useEffect with props.location.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';

const SampleComponent = (props) => {

      useEffect(() => {
        console.log(props.location);
      }, [props.location]);

}

export default SampleComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `useEffect` hook it's possible to detect route changes without adding a listener.

```js
import React, { useEffect }           from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, withRouter }  from 'react-router-dom';
import Main                           from './Main';
import Blog                           from './Blog';


const App  = ({history}) => {

    useEffect( () => {

        // When route changes, history.location.pathname changes as well
        // And the code will execute after this line

    }, [history.location.pathname]);

    return (<Switch>
              <Route exact path = '/'     component = {Main}/>
              <Route exact path = '/blog' component = {Blog}/>
            </Switch>);

}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with this problem, so I'll add my solution as a supplement on other answers given.

The problem here is that `useEffect` doesn't really work as you would want it to, since the call only gets triggered after the first render so there is an unwanted delay.
If you use some state manager like redux, chances are that you will get a flicker on the screen because of lingering state in the store.

What you really want is to use `useLayoutEffect` since this gets triggered immediately.

So I wrote a small utility function that I put in the same directory as my router:

```
export const callApis = (fn, path) => {
    useLayoutEffect(() => {
      fn();
    }, [path]);
};
```

Which I call from within the component HOC like this:

```
callApis(() => getTopicById({topicId}), path);
```

`path` is the prop that gets passed in the `match` object when using `withRouter`.

I'm not really in favour of listening / unlistening manually on history.
That's just imo.