# Get site control feedback widget not loading in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, external, browser-history

I recently changed to use browserHistory from hashHistory in a react app. The get site control feedback widget used to work without any problem with the different urls in the app.But its not working after the change. E.g at www.xxx.com, the widget works but at www.xxx.com/yyy, it does not work.

When I inspect the element, i can see the scripts needed to load the widget. I am wondering if it is something related to browswerHistory thing.
Would highly appreciate, if anyone has any idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

it's not very clear what goes wrong
but I guess you need to tell widgets on which page your app is.

Take a look at API docs:

[Tracking pages in Single Page Apps](https://getsitecontrol.com/howto/developer-documentation/how-use-getsitecontrol-widget-api/#tracking-pages-in-single-page-apps)

And if you are using React router you need to listen to route changes:

[How to listen to route changes in react router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911309/how-to-listen-to-route-changes-in-react-router-v4)

Comment: I actually found a solution. I had to make a small change in the setting of getsitecontrol dashboard. I added * on the target url after slash (/). www.xyz.com/*

Comment: thank you @Alexander Rusanov. You gave me some hints to look into the dashboar :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a solution. Its actually getsitecontrol that is making not to display in other pagers. I had to make a small change in the setting of getsitecontrol dashboard. I added * on the target url after slash (/). www.xyz.com/*
It had nothing to do with browserHistory as I thought before.