# react-router4 global hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there a global hook or single router hook in react-router4? or some good custom impementation? this feature is really quite useful.

I also use Vue, it's offical implementation is like below:
`javascript
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {...})`

I can do some block things, like api request etc.

Comment: So, to clarify, do you mean the same thing shown here?:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911309/how-to-listen-to-route-changes-in-react-router-v4

Comment: no, jusk like. I just want to do something when I match the route before the component start it's life cycle, even some async operations.