# React Router: logging every access to a specific route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In React, I have code like this:

```
<Router basename='/app'>
  <main>
    <Menu active={menu} close={this.closeMenu} />
    <Overlay active={menu} onClick={this.closeMenu} />
    <AppBar handleMenuIcon={this.handleMenuIcon} title='Test' />
    <Route path='/customers/:id' component={Customers} />
    <Route path='/products/:id' component={Products} />
  </main>
</Router>
```

Every time `/customers/:id` or `/products/:id` is accessed, I want to log the access by making an ajax call to a backend service. The fields I will be logging include the referrer URL, the current URL, and a randomly generated session ID (random base 64 integer)  What's the best way to do that when I am using the `Router` component from [`react-router`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) version 1.0.0.

Comment: Because React code executes on the client, a better approach would be to log requests on the server-side.

Comment: @Richard Isn't that what they asked for? " I want to log the access by making an ajax call to a backend service"

Comment: The user wants to 'log the access by making an ajax call.' A better approach would be to log the request when it happens on the express/koa/rails/whatever server is serving the API data.

Comment: @Richard Oh, you're saying that on the API side to log it there rather than make a *separate* Ajax call? That's fine if the data is coming from the server (which it may not be) or that they have the ability to modify the API code (which may not be the case).

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered with this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/44410281/5746996

But in essense:

```
@withRouter
class App extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    location: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
  }

  // ...

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      this.onRouteChanged();
    }
  }

  onRouteChanged() {
    console.log("ROUTE CHANGED");
  }

  // ...
  render(){
    return <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/checkout" component={CheckoutPage} />
        <Route path="/success" component={SuccessPage} />
        // ...
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
  }
}
```

Use the `location` property in the `props` property when you have added the `react-router`. Test to see if it has changed with each update - if it has, you can send it.

Comment: So it's a dupe?