# How to disable scroller specify page in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

I'm working my university project and i have a 4 pages , I want to know how to disable scrolling option only specific page. I'm using following code part, but its apply overall pages. any one have a solution ?

```
componentWillMount(){
        document.body.style.overflow='hidden'
    }
```

```
  export class MyBook extends React.Component<any, any> {
        
         render() {
               
                return (
<div></div>
       )
        }
        
}
```

Comment: Set it back to `auto` when you need to have scroll. [`history.listen`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62049352/2873538) may be useful.

Comment: @AjeetShah Hello there, where is to adding this?

Comment: you can use [componentWillUnmount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) method to reset the property `overflow` back to `auto`

Comment: @AjeetShah But I want to disable scrolling only one page, I added you mentions answer but not working. So can you please put the answer?

Comment: @kunalpanchal ,I added you mentions answer but not working, So can you please put the answer?

Comment: one more solution for you may be you can do it using css as you want it just for one single page you can add `height:100%` to the first parent element of the component and assign the `overflow:hidden` property to it and remove the JavaScript code which is not need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can

```
<Pages>
  <Page1 />
  <Page2 />
  ...
</ Pages>
```

If you use clas approach

```
class Page2 extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
      document.body.style.overflow='hidden'
   }

   componentWillUnMount() {
      document.body.style.overflow='auto'
   }
}
```

If you use func approach

```
useEffect(() => {
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    return () => {
      document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
    };
  }, []);
```

be careful that componentWillMount depricated now