# How to detect/handle back button press in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to detect a user pressing the back button. I have a component that logs POP every time, even when the user did not press back button. I want to run this code only when the user navigated to the component from another screen. How do I do this?

```
const history = useHistory();
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(history.action)
    if (history.action == 'POP') {
        // process
}, [data])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911309/how-to-listen-to-route-changes-in-react-router-v4

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish here but I think you could use the `return` in useEffect to check when the user goes back. `return` runs when the component is unmounted.

```
const history = useHistory();
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(history.action)
    if (history.action == 'POP') {
        
        return function cleanup() {console.log("User pressed back")};
}, [data])
```