# How to track react-ga events with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, react-router-dom, react-ga

I want to track events with react-ga in my web app project. I used react-router-dom for my routing and I always used Link to redirect users. An example from my header - directing the user towards the "explore" page:

```
<Link to="/explore">
                <Icon
                  icon={pathname === "/explore" ? "compass" : "compass-outline"}
                />
              </Link>
```

How exactly to track the event "user went to '/explore'"
The only guides I can find show me how to track events caused by buttons and onClick().
I have already connected my app to google analytics and it detects my current location just fine.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    ReactGa.initialize("UA-175518918-1");
    ReactGa.pageview(window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here:

1. You can use Link component like this:

```
<Link to="/explore" onClick={e=>ReactGa.pageview('explore')}>Explore</Link>
```

2. You can listen to route changes, depending on the version of the react-router the code of how to do it will vary:

- If you use react-router-3 you can use `listen` method for `history`:

```
history.listen((location) => {
  ReactGa.pageview(location.pathname);
})
```

- If you use react-router-4 you can take a look at the solution here: [How to listen to route changes in react router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911309/how-to-listen-to-route-changes-in-react-router-v4/57356519)