# React execute common code on each route change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component included in my App.js and that component contains some common logic which needs to be executed.

So my App component JSX looks like

```
<CommonComponent />
    {canRenderBool && (
    <div class="container">
        <Route exact path="/comp1">
        <Comp1 />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/comp2">
        <Comp2 />
        </Route>
        </div>
)
}
```

Now, I want that on each route transition (e.g. user clicks on a new route url), I want that the code in CommonComponent (non-routable component) gets triggered.
This common component has logic which returns a boolean variable and I kind of render/not render Comp1/Comp2 i.e. all the routes based on that boolean

What is the best way I can handle it. I want to avoid having that code defined/invoked in each component manually?

Also most of my components are functional/hooks based.

Comment: Is CommonComponent the parent of comp1 and comp2? I see no closing tag.

Comment: Oh sorry...updated...No CommonComponent is child of App and kind of sibling to comp1 and comp2

Comment: Also just to add, this common component has logic which returns a boolean variable and I kind of render/not render Comp1/Comp2 i.e. all the routes based on that boolean

Comment: Updated code so that you can get an idea

Comment: I think this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911309/how-to-listen-to-route-changes-in-react-router-v4. I'm thinking you can define canRenderBool as a state in the parent of your JSX, create a listener for the history object, and pass down the URL, for example, down to CommonComponent as a prop. This way, when the URL changes CommonComponent will be rerendered and if you pass setCanRenderBool to CommonComponent as a prop, you can inform the parent JSX of changes in that bool.

Comment: Actually in my case, this is in the App component...so no parent as such...Not sure if that would still work...

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using functional component for your `App` Component. You can write your `CommonComponent` logic inside `useEffect` and then there you can set state for your `canRenderBool` flag

for example

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const [canRenderBool , setCanRenderBool] = useState(false);
  const location = useLocation(); // this will only work if you wrap your App component in a Router

  // this effect will run on every route change
  useEffect(() => {
    // your logic here
    // ..

    // set value of 'canRenderBool' flag
    setCanRenderBool(true);
  }, [location]);

  return (
    // Note that Router is not used here it will be wraped when we export this component, see below
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Page1 />
      </Route>

      {canRenderBool && (
        <Route exact path="/page-2">
          <Page2 />
        </Route>
      )}
    </Switch>
  );
}

function Page1() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        Go to <Link to="/page-2">Page 2</Link>
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

function Page2() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        Go to <Link to="/">Page 1</Link>
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

// Wrapping Router around App and exporting
export default () => (
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{canRenderBool && (
 <Router>
  <div class="container">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/comp1"> <Comp1 /> </Route>
        <Route exact path="/comp2"> <Comp2 /> </Route>
      </Switch>
    <Link to="/comp1">Component 1</Link>
    <Link to="/comp2">Component 2</Link>
  </div>
 </Router>
)
}
```

This might help. And you will need to import all keywords and components before using them.