# Check destination (next location) via React Router on page leave

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there a way to check the next location via React Router? I am not interested in using [Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841757/detecting-user-leaving-page-with-react-router) solution. My goal is to set some condition on component unmount like:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    if(nextRoute !== '/something') {
      resetData();
    }
  };
}, []);
```

Is there a way to have a knowledge what is the `nextRoute`?

Comment: Why not run `resetData()` from within the component that handles `'/something'` route within a useEffect()?

Comment: Hey, good question, My bad, I've just edited the question. I want to resetData always but not for this one particular route.

Comment: You should be able to reach for the location object within props and do something like the below
`const something = ({location}) => {

useEffect(() => { 
  if(location.pathname !== '/something') resetData();
 }, [location])

return ( // some jsx)
}`

Comment: Yeah but in such case I will reach the CURRENT location, my point is to get the NEXT location (destination) that the user is redirecting to

Comment: Hmm, I'd probably say that you would need to run a callback from the onClick event that occurs on route change, or run a function to do a similar method. That is of course if the user is interacting with a link that will push them to another route, just that useEffect is a lifecycle adaption for component mounting/unmounting/remounting.
How does the user reach the next page, from a Route click?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911309/how-to-listen-to-route-changes-in-react-router-v4