# How to listen to route changes with react-native

Tags: react-native, react-router

I'm trying to listen to route changes via event. I read somewhere to use the history package:

```
  import history from 'history/browser';


  // Listen for changes to the current location.
  const unlisten = history.listen(({ location, action }) => {
     console.log(action, location.pathname, location.state);
  });
```

Unluckily as I call the history api I get this error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: document

Which is pretty obvious, as I'm not in a web-browser. Then my question is:

How can I listen/intercept/block routes change from inside a component in react-native?

Answer (score 0):

Try to extract history from your component and then just add the `history.location.pathname` to the dependencies of a `useEffect`. Then on every change of route the `useEffect` will get called.

like:

```js
const App  = ({history}) => {

    useEffect( () => {

        // When route changes, history.location.pathname changes as well
        // And the code will execute after this line

    }, [history.location.pathname]);

....
```

Credits to: [Erik Martín Jordán](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911309/how-to-listen-to-route-changes-in-react-router-v4)

Comment: What do you mean by "extract history"?

Comment: @Nemus `App` has `props`. `children` for example, in a default prop of every react (native) component. If you wrap your app in a `NavigationContainer` then navigation props are included. These you can extract with {...}. Otherwise, you can do `props.history`.

Comment: In react router v6 there is no API named "navigation Container"

Comment: @Nemus, oops, no there is not! It's from React Navigation. Sorry! But the `extract` theory counts the same... Thanks