# Mounting external scripts that transform the DOM in React Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, gatsby

Needing a solution to a problem that I have asked in many ways without resolve.

I have external scripts from TripAdvisor that are being mounted in a component as `componentDidMount`. Also `shouldComponentUpdate()` as `false` to avoid future `eventListeners` also mounted by `componentDidMount` in the `layouts/index.js` from affecting the TripAdvisor content to disappear due to re-render of the DOM.

```
componentDidMount () {
    const tripadvisorLeft = document.createElement("script");
    tripadvisorLeft.src = "https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&uniq=789&locationId=10467767&lang=en_AU&rating=true&nreviews=0&writereviewlink=true&popIdx=true&iswide=true&border=false&display_version=2";
    document.body.appendChild(tripadvisorLeft);

    const tripadvisorRight = document.createElement("script");
    tripadvisorRight.src = "https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&uniq=998&locationId=10467767&lang=en_AU&rating=false&nreviews=4&writereviewlink=false&popIdx=false&iswide=true&border=false&display_version=2";
    document.body.appendChild(tripadvisorRight);
}

shouldComponentUpdate() {
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that when using `Link` by either `react-route` or `gatsby-link` to and from the page that contains the component the content from TripAdvisor is not rendered.

If I refresh the browser on the page - the content is available.
See here - [example](https://gracious-allen-d5eb54.netlify.com/varenna/reviews)

How can I `unmount`, `forceUpdate` or any other solution to getting these scripts re-render on `route change`?

Full source code can be found [here](https://github.com/discovr-bookings/mountainWhispers).

Comment: isn't it a repost of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893481/remount-componentdidmount-by-path-name) ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. I had not received the right answer and so decided to change the question slightly. Obviously it worked as you have answered with a solution that works. if you want to leave remove your answer from her and put it o the other I will accept and you'll get the bounty. I'l then remove this question.

Comment: yeah you are right. I'll leave my answer here, maybe it will give someone an idea for a simple and better solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the **TripAdvisor** script is creating a function called `injectselfserveprop***`. (where `***` are random numbers).

This function is responsible to display the HTML code of the **TripAdvisor** widget.

However, for obscure reason this function is not called when you reach the Component with `Link`.

This is one solution for your issue, and might not be the best:

#### 1) Define your script tags in src/layouts/index.js

Because the **TripAdvisor**' script creates these functions, we have to define the scripts before rendering the `TripAdvisor` component.

```
<Helmet>
  // ...
  <script src={`https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&uniq=789&locationId=10467767&lang=en_AU&rating=true&nreviews=0&writereviewlink=true&popIdx=true&iswide=true&border=false&display_version=2`}/>
  <script src={`https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&uniq=998&locationId=10467767&lang=en_AU&rating=false&nreviews=4&writereviewlink=false&popIdx=false&iswide=true&border=false&display_version=2`}/>
</Helmet>
```

#### 2) call the `injectselfserveprop` functions on `TripAdvisor` componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount() {
  // find any function that begins with 'injectselfserveprop'
  // and execute it.
  Object.keys(window).forEach((key) => {
    if (key.match(/^injectselfserveprop[0-9]+$/)) {
      window[key]();
    }
  });
}
```

I have tried this and it works for me.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. This has worked for me. However it does open another question. If you open the URL https://gracious-allen-d5eb54.netlify.com/strawberry-patch/reviews the script is presenting the data, however if you load any page prior, such as https://gracious-allen-d5eb54.netlify.com/strawberry-patch/rates-packages the `/reviews` path does not load the script on first entry.

Comment: Yes that's my little "hacks" on the 1st part of my anwser: define the <script> tags in your `src/layouts/index.js`. According to your github repo, you still call the scripts on `TripAdvisor` component which is not what I mentionned in my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot have these scripts loading from `layouts/index.js`. Reason is that there are multiple properties, each with their own `locationID` I have put back to `templates/properties/reviews.js` of which doesn't make any difference but is at the root of the `createPages`

Comment: Oh ok I understand. What if you put the scripts on `templates/properties.js` ? You need to find the common ancestors where the <script> will be mounted.

Does putting all your properties scripts with their associated `locationId` in `layout/index.js` a relevent solution ?

Finally, if none of this works, I think you could do in all of your templates' `componentDidMount()` [something like this](https://gist.github.com/nenu-git/f9f656ba187a0dc21811b5a081762956)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I get the same response via your method suggested. I am going to look into perhaps other methods of fetching the data. I know that TripAdvisor have a content API so I will look into accessing this. Thank you for your help and I have accepted your answer as it is correct to the issue I originally outlined.

Comment: Alright ! It looks like an issue is always hiding in solutions... Thanks for the accepted answer and good luck with that :)