# Pull GraphQL data into gatsby-browser.js (or better solution, please)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to run a **GraphQL** query inside `replaceRouterComponent` from within `gatsby-browser.js` ([gatsby browser API](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/)). Whereas, I can access data from **[Contentful](https://www.contentful.com/)**.

This may not be the best solution and any advice on how I can achieve in another way would be appreciated too.

**Here is the issue -**

Inside of the component **TripAdvisor.js** I am mounting the scripts within `componentDidMount`, whereas the `locationId` is based on the data of `this.props.tripAdvisorId` pulled from the individual `posts` created in **Contentful**. Each `post` (property) has an individual `locationId` that when changed in the script `src` presents the reviews that relate.

```
componentDidMount () {
    const tripadvisorLeft = document.createElement("script");
    tripadvisorLeft.src = "https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&uniq=789&locationId=" + this.props.tripAdvisorId + "&lang=en_AU&rating=true&nreviews=0&writereviewlink=true&popIdx=true&iswide=true&border=false&display_version=2";
    tripadvisorLeft.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(tripadvisorLeft);

    const tripadvisorRight = document.createElement("script");
    tripadvisorRight.src = "https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&uniq=998&locationId=" + this.props.tripAdvisorId + "&lang=en_AU&rating=false&nreviews=4&writereviewlink=false&popIdx=false&iswide=true&border=false&display_version=2";
    tripadvisorRight.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(tripadvisorRight);
}
```

I also have a function inside `componentDidMount` at page level to rewrite the data from the TripAdvisor script above. The TripAdvisor script creates a function called injectselfserveprop*** (where *** are random numbers). Without this, the function is not called when reaching the Component with `Link`

**/templates/properties/reviews.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
  Object.keys(window).forEach((key) => {
      if (key.match(/^injectselfserveprop[0-9]+$/)) {
          window[key]();
      }
  });
}
```

In the same file of **/templates/properties/reviews.js** I use `shouldComponentUpdate` to `return false` as it stops the **TripAdvisor** from continually updating between pages (causing it to break) when using `link`

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
  return false;
}
```

Now, where this solution falls apart is in changing the `locationId` of the script `src`. It works perfectly fine if I did not need to change the `locationId` per `post`.

It fails when `link` to another `post` with a different `locationId` and the reviews component not updating. However, then `link` away and return to the new reviews.

You can see this happening [here](https://gracious-allen-d5eb54.netlify.com/chatelaine/reviews) and following these steps -

1. Click this [link](https://gracious-allen-d5eb54.netlify.com/chatelaine/reviews) and scroll down to see the reviews related to Chatelaine
2. Then in the menu > select Varenna > select Reviews in the horizontal menu and you still see Chatelaine reviews.
3. Now, click on > Location in the horizontal menu > then click Reviews again > you get the correct reviews and count for Varenna.

There is a GitHub repository for the full site [here](https://github.com/discovr-bookings/mountainWhispers). The two files to look for are in `/src/templates/properties/reviews.js` and `src/components/properties/TripAdvisor.js`

Now I have outlined my issue, I believe the best solution is within `gatsby-browser.js` wrapping the TripAdvisor scripts inside `replaceRouterComponent` with a conditional statement to apply only to pages that directly access the `reviews.js` via `Link`.

However, I cannot find a solution in using the `tripAdvisorID` data inside `gatsby-browser.js` ([gatsby browser API](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/)). Whereas, I can access data from **[Contentful](https://www.contentful.com/)** using **GraphQL**.

If you have another solution then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, If your problem is the updating the component maybe the problem is in the way you are dealing with side effects (the `componentDidMount` fetch in TripAdvisor).

For what I can see, the data that you receive in props is all good, and it should fetch, but there is an error. `componentDidMount` will **ONLY BE CALLED ONCE**, and this time is the first time the component has been loaded in the page. So it doesnt matter that your props change and that you render again, the code in `componentDidMount` **won't be called again**.

You could do the fix in 2 ways. Rather you add key in

```
 <TripAdvisor key={tripAdvisorId} name={name} starRating={starRating} location={location} tripAdvisorId={tripAdvisorId} * />
```

This way react will unmount the previous TripAdvisor and mount a new one thereby calling the componentDidMount method again... What could be a bit of a problem if you have to be remounting everything just for a different data from the props....

I could recommend you a second way, that is also the way they recommend in the [React Documentation.](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#side-effects-on-props-change) Instead of realizing your changes in `componentDidMount`, do them in `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState)` (NOTE: You will need to safe your fetch by `this.props.tripAdvisorId !== prevProps.tripAdvisorId` or you will enter a infinite loop).

I think that this is the problem for you to update the data, nothing gatsby related... But comment me if the problem persist and I could check further into the GraphQL problems that you are running into.